# How to reset a panel to its initial state

Tags: panel

I've created a panel with a number of other panels into it. Using it, I open panel by panel for doing my work.

Then I've added an operator to reset its properties to their default state.
I'd like this operator to reset the panel state, too, so its subpanels are all closed. There are a lot of them, and I don't want to close them one by one.

For instance, when we do CTRL-N or File - new, the panel restarts with all subpanels closed.
Does someone know how to achieve this with operator code?

Thank you

Comment: AFAIK it's still pretty much put '`DEFAULT_CLOSED`' in the options and toggle registration.

Comment: Tried your idea - it destroys and recreate the panel, but to my surprise the subpanels are still open, lol, like it did nothing... so probably is st related to the scene, like resetting ui vars which track panel position, width, and so on... thank you